# Query to XML Node is giving me NULL Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Trying to achieve what stored procedure used for each report in Report Server.

```
INSERT INTO #ReportRawXML
    SELECT  
        ItemID, RPT.[Name] AS ReportName,
        CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), RPT.Content)) AS XMLdata
    FROM    
        ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] AS RPT
    WHERE 
        RPT.[Name] LIKE '%catalog%'
```

XML sample:

```
<Report>
<DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DSET_ReportRepository">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>CCA_PROD</DataSourceName>
    </Query>
</DataSets>
</Report>
```

I have a table with a `XML` column which I want to query, but I'm getting NULL back; I tried all possible ways, please someone advice.

```
SELECT 
    b.ItemID, b.ReportName,
    n.c.value('@DataSourceName', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS id,
    n.c.value('/DataSourceName[1]', 'VARCHAR(500)') AS DataSourceName,
    n.c.value('/CommandType[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS CommandType,
    n.c.value('/CommandText[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS CommandText
FROM    
    #ReportRawXML b
OUTER APPLY 
    b.XMLdata.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query') AS n(c)
```

Question: getting NULL in column 3 above

Comment: How do you suppose anyone would be able to help you without seeing the XML?

Comment: ...although I suspect that you might get results when you use `./` instead of `/` to start your XPath expressions.

Comment: If you are getting `NULL` values for `CommandType`, then that means you are embedding the query in the `CommandText` and not calling a `stored procedure`. Are there values in the `CommandText` column?

Comment: Without seing your XML any help is pure guessing...

Comment: I have edited the post , if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for your next question:

- Please try to add a MCVE (a *stand-alone-sample* as I provide it here for you) right from the start. You know all your details, but we don't...
- Try to add a sample, where the sample includes everything (e.g. your sample does not show any `CommandType` or `CommandText`
- Please read about the internal formatting tools on SO how to add code, normal text, how to highlight or cite...
- Please run your sample yourself. Doing so, you would have found, that the XML provided is not well-formed (missing `</DataSet>`).

But now to your question:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, XMLdata XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
(N'<Report>
    <DataSets>
        <DataSet Name="DSET_ReportRepository">
          <Query>
            <DataSourceName>CCA_PROD</DataSourceName>
          </Query>
        </DataSet>
    </DataSets> 
</Report>');
```

--The query

```
SELECT b.ID
      ,ds.value('(Query/DataSourceName/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as id
      ,ds.value('@Name', 'varchar(max)') as id
FROM    @mockupTable b
OUTER APPLY b.XMLdata.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet') as  n(ds);
```

Reading from XML you must know, that the `@` before the name indicates an attribute. To read the `DataSet`'s `Name` attribute, you need this, but not before `DataSourceName` as in your own attempt.